# sort a list of strings by the number of words in the string

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I have a list of strings as such:

```
mylist = ["superduperlongstring", "a short string", "the middle"]
```

I want to sort this in such a way that the string with the largest number of words is first, ie,

```
mylist = ["a short string", "the middle", "superduperlongstring"]
```

Its a bit tricky, since if I sort in place by length

```
mylist.sort(key = len)
```

I'm back where I started.

Has anyone come across a graceful solution to this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that words are separated by whitespace, calling [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with no arguments returns a list of the words that a string contains:

```
>>> "superduperlongstring".split()
['superduperlongstring']
>>> "a short string".split()
['a', 'short', 'string']
>>> "the middle".split()
['the', 'middle']
>>>
```

Therefore, you can get the output you want by sorting `mylist` based off of the length of these lists:

```
>>> mylist = ["superduperlongstring", "a short string", "the middle"]
>>> mylist.sort(key=lambda x: len(x.split()), reverse=True)
>>> mylist
['a short string', 'the middle', 'superduperlongstring']
>>>
```

You will also need to set the `reverse` parameter of `list.sort` to `True`, as shown above.