# python sorting from large to small

Tags: python-3.x

text1 = 'We are not what we should be We are not what we need to be But at least we are not what we used to be -- Football Coach'

i have this text1 and here is the code  for it

```
def word_dict(all_words): 
    word_dict = {}
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    text = text1.split()
    for line in text:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            word = word.lower()
            if not word in word_dict:
                word_dict[word] = 1
            else:
                word_dict[word] = word_dict[word] + 1
    return word_dict
```

I am counting each and every word in text one , but i want to do when i am displaying , i want to displaying from the lagest to the smallest number of counts of word

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sort a list of strings by the number of words in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128380/sort-a-list-of-strings-by-the-number-of-words-in-the-string)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sorted` to sort words by length.

```
textArr = text1.split()
result = sorted(textArr , key = len)
```

Comment: I nid to ryt that as another function . do i do like this?

Comment: def print_top(text1, top = 20):
    # YOUR CODE HERE
   sorted(text1 , key = len)
    return dict2

Comment: def print_top(text1, top = 20):
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    dict2 = {}
    textArr = text1.split()
    word_d =  word_dict(textArr)
    for k, v in word_d.items():
        dict2[k] = str(v)
        sorted = sorted(textArr , key = len)
    return dict2         i have this function to display from lagest to smallest but i am getting this error 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sorted' referenced before assignment'

Comment: Don't name your variables `sorted`, this shadows the built-in.